# Have GoT's showrunners reacted to the poor reception of the final season?

Tags: game-of-thrones, production, reception

The final season of Game of Thrones is coming to an end but many fans are disappointed by the rushed conclusion of the final episodes. Ratings for season 8 have taken a ["critical nosedive"](https://qz.com/quartzy/1618479/data-show-game-of-thrones-is-taking-a-historic-critical-nosedive/) and some fans [have demanded that season 8 be rewritten](https://globalnews.ca/news/5280447/game-of-thrones-season-8-petition/). Many people are also [concerned for the next Star Wars saga](https://comicbook.com/starwars/2019/05/15/game-of-thrones-fans-react-star-wars-movies-angry-backlash/), which should be written and produced by D. Benioff and D.B Weiss, and fear that the storyline will suffer from issues similar to those of GoT's latest season.

My question is: where are D. Benioff and D.B Weiss in all of this? Have they reacted to the poor reception of the show? Have they tried to justify and explain some of the divisive choices they made in the last season (besides in the "Inside the episode" featurettes where they act as if everyone would love the conclusion of the show)?

Before the season premiere they announced they [would get drunk in a remote location](https://www.indiewire.com/2019/04/game-of-thrones-creators-drunk-far-from-internet-series-finale-airs-1202057274/) without their cellphones and far from the Internet during the show's finale. But I doubt they spent the whole season in this remote location, so I guess they are aware that the ratings have gotten lower and lower in the past weeks. Are they waiting for the dust to settle before they respond to the criticism of the show?

Comment: Okay people, this thing's gonna get huge sooner or later anyway. But, please try to not make me dig out the comment lock from the moderator tools. The question does a good job of *not* discussing if the criticism is justified nor what it says about Benioff and Weiss, so let's try to keep it at that for as long as possible. Thank you.

Comment: Related: [Have the writers and actors of GOT responded to its poor reception?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/212606)

Answer (score 30, accepted):

## No, they have not responded.

After scanning several search platforms for several minutes I have concluded that no such interview exists, although they must be aware of the dislike. Some of the cast have responded and put out their opinion about the last season one of whom was Euron Greyjoy (Pilou Asbæk)

> "The diversity of the fans and the passion they bring to the table is
>   admirable, and you want to have all of it.
>
> "You want to have the ones that go, 'This is the greatest show ever
>   made,' and you wanna have the people that go, 'I hate this show. I've
>   always hated it. I want the books now.'
>
> "You cannot satisfy one billion people, it's not possible. But you
>   want to have them commit to the show, even if they don't like it.
>   There was a guy called PT Barnum who said, 'There's no such thing as
>   bad press, there's only press'."
>
> "And I welcome everyone – people I agree with or people I disagree
>   with," he continued. "And I have on social media been discussing Game
>   of Thrones with fans and I will continue to do that, because you owe
>   the fans information and they need a place where they can ask
>   questions about what they like or dislike and it's totally cool, it's
>   passionate. And you've gotta love that.
>
> "Besides that, for me, the twists and turns were logical, because this
>   is Game of Thrones, and people have to die. And I would be very, very
>   surprised if we end up with a happy ending next week. I know how it's
>   gonna end, so I'm not gonna say a word.
>
> "But Dan (Weiss) and David (Benioff) have delivered for seven seasons
>   admirable content and I would say they have delivered extremely well
>   again this season. But again, you can't please everyone."
>
> ---
>
> <sub>[‘Game of Thrones': Euron Actor Pilou Asbaek on Why a ‘Very Important’ Scene Wasn’t Shown on Screen - TheWrap](https://www.thewrap.com/game-of-thrones-euron-greyjoy-death-pilou-asbaek-cersei-jaime-series-finale/)</sub>

Seeing as the actors are now defending D.B. Weiss and David Benioff it is evident they are aware of the dislike but don't care to comment.

Other than this (thanks to @KRyan) it seems like some other cast members are shying away from commenting of what they think about the eighth season as shown in this little compilation.

I'm having trouble with transcribing some of the content seeing as there is so much background chatter, but it mostly consists of cast and crew members uncomfortably laughing off the question, "Are you happy with how things ended?"

Some more quotes are available about the Cast's thoughts about season 8 over [here](http://time.com/5389324/game-of-thrones-cast-season-8-hints/).

Comment: There was a guy called Oscar Wilde who said "the only thing worse than being talked about is not being talked about".

Comment: It may be worth noting [this answer from a highly-similar question on SF&F](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/212608/7700), where numerous actors (aside from Pilou Asbæk, I guess) avoid defending S8. Emilia Clarke gets flustered and laughs and gives an almost-sarcastic “best season ever!” Isaac Hempstead Wright avoids answering while Liam Cunningham just laughs at the question, and Nikolai Coster-Waldau actually had an interview that was heavily critical of the screenwriters (but then, his critique apparently goes back to S4, so I’m not sure how to take that). Etc.

Comment: It's odd that the answers to my question and this question are so different

Comment: @AlecA you asked about the writers and actors, this question just asks about the writers. Note the end of the answer your question got says much the same on the subject: "As far as I know the writers and/or directors have yet to comment"

Comment: @KRyan I’m somewhat afraid that the editing of these clips makes them quite misleading, and might be taking the replies out of context. That said, I wouldn’t be surprised if they were true.

Comment: @KonradRudolph Agreed, a couple of them get cut off and make you wonder if they weren’t about to say something positive—though the lack of immediate “oh yes, it’s great!” that you might expect could be telling. Anyway, at least a few of the actors are really quite explicit about it. The first word out of Kit Harrington’s mouth to describe the ending was “disappointing.” I mean, that’s... really saying something, even if he responds to the interviewer’s shock with “Or epic, I don’t know. One of those.” Not the sterling endorsement you’d expect from the stars of the show.